# How to generate/view PDF using Lightning Components?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I need to view/generate PDF in Lightning component. How can I achieve that?

Do I have to user VF page with "renderAs" attribute inside Lightning Component? Or is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two methods to show a PDF in `Lightning Component`.

- First, you can create a `Visualforce page` and embed it in the
  `Lightning component`. See detailed example [here](http://www.vermanshul.com/2017/07/lightning-generate-pdf-from-lightning.html)
- Second is, usage of `PDF.JS` library to directly use `lightning component` to display the `PDF`. See details [here](https://medium.com/my-journey-with-salesforce1-platform/pdf-viewer-lightning-component-f96e6a5704ab) .Entire source
  code can be found [here](https://github.com/kumarrk21/PDFViewer).

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: How can I embed VF page in lightning? I am unable to see any output when I use <iframe> tag to include VF page.

Comment: Example at this link didn't help? http://www.vermanshul.com/2017/07/lightning-generate-pdf-from-lightning.html

Comment: The link was helpful. But how can I use it in lightning components? The example you mentioned makes use of lightning component in VF page. What I need is to generate/view PDF from lightning component.

Comment: What abt second option?

Answer (score 3):

You can embed a vfPage (renderas="pdf") in lightning component and utilize the component in required place.

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
<iframe src="{! '/apex/pdfPage'}" width="100%" height="500px;" frameBorder="0"/>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

As of 2020, I'm having good results with the lwc viewer at [github.com/annyhe/pdfViewer](http://github.com/annyhe/pdfViewer) Doesn't require visualforce

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check the below PDF viewer which works well in all scenarios.

> https://hellosnl.blogspot.com/2019/10/pdf-reader-as-salesforce-lightning-web-component.html

This is based on PDF.js library to render a PDF document inside an iframe. Code is provided in the github repo, the link of which you can get in the blog post.

Comment: Tried using this solution and it doesn't seem to work. Posted the question about same here salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/354812/…. Would love to have some guidance regarding this

Comment: This still works. Please check your code again.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.