# Best Approach to Render a PDF from External Source Without Storing File and Preventing User Download On Mobile

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, pdf

I am working on a requirement to display a PDF that is returned from an external application. I've written the Apex class that will authenticate and then return the PDF document in a HTTP Get response.

Given these documents contain sensitive information, we do **not** want to store the PDF in Salesforce (e.g. create a ContentVersion or File record using the PDF). Also, if viewing from the Salesforce mobile app, we want to **avoid** users' being able to open the PDF in other apps or downloading them.

I've started my approach of using a Lighting Web Component that will call the Apex class to return the PDF. However, I'm not sure this is a viable option to continue to pursue.

I've read about the PDF.js library, as well as many examples posted online for LWC or Aura Components. Plenty of them rely on the document being stored in Salesforce, or are Aura Components instead of LWC.

We are in Lightning and would need a working approach for Desktop too. Preferably, I'd be able to use the same component for both desktop and mobile, and not have to pursue different frameworks for each device type (i.e. Aura for mobile and LWC for desktop).

What approach would be recommended for this? I'm not certain a Lightning Web Component is going to work. Should I double back to Aura Components? Pursue embedding a Visualforce page as PDF? I have limited time so I want to avoid building something then learning I won't be able to meet one of the requirements outlined above.

This older question was answered before Lightning Web Components existed: [How to generate/view PDF using Lightning Components?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/205065/how-to-generate-view-pdf-using-lightning-components)
The answers are limited to using Aura Components.
Here is an explanation which highlights differences between Aura and LWC:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.migrate_map_aura_lwc_components

Comment: Check this one -- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/205065/how-to-generate-view-pdf-using-lightning-components

Comment: Hi @kurunve - I've seen that one and read over the linked documentation/blog posts too. It would mean I'd need to go with Lightning Aura Components if I were to use that example as a guide. Do we think an LWC won't be viable?

Comment: Not really @identigral - those are potential approaches if I wanted to use Aura Components. The new framework Lightning Web Components is what I'm initially trying to use. I was hoping this community can provide insight as to if I will meet my requirements using Lightning Web Components or need to try using Aura Components like suggested in that old question.

Comment: `pdf.js` [works](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/285052/i-cant-load-pdf-js-lib-in-lightning-web-component) in pure Lightning.